# Can I include html5shiv for all browsers?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Here is the situation - I am using the HTML5 "main" tag on my site, but as it turns out, IE doesn't support and it doesn't display it at all.

I am using the html5shiv script (https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) and was wondering if it will be a problem to include it non-conditionally - for all the browsers. Can I expect any problems with that?

In their site they don't mention anything about using it non-conditionally.

I tried using the "if IE" conditional tag, but it seems IE10 is too modern browser and it doesn't support it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
main {display: block;}
```

in your Stylehseet.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use it with a conditional statement to identify IE versions that need it. There are many sample HTML5 DTD declarations on the net that implement html5shiv correctly and gave been tried and tested with many browsers.